# Looking for Antlr Grammar syntaxt highlight in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, syntax-highlighting, antlr, grammar, antlrworks

I am looking for some way to edit antlr grammar files directly within VS2010 with syntax highlight.

I have used antlrworks a lot but it has the drawback that I have to start antlrworks separately and then browse to the file I want to edit, do the changed and save. For minor fixes I do not need all the tools in Antlrworks but I still would like the syntax highlight.

But I have not been able to get VS2010 to open antlrworks with the right file and I have found no other way to get syntax highlight directly within VS2010 editor, it just opens as plain text.

I can get visual studio to open antlrworks but it will open with only the last set of files it had open, not the one I clicked on.

So my question(s) are:

Is there a way to get antlrworks to open with the right file when I double click in it in visual studio project explorer?

Is there any other way to get correct syntax highlight for antlr grammar files within visual studio (or with another editor, preferably not one that costs money, but if there are no free ones a commercial one might be an option).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide a custom parser class that Visual Studio uses to highlight ANTLR grammar files.

See: [Syntax Colorizing (Managed Package Framework)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165041%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: I'll accepting this solution as it would solve my problem, but the work required to build a lexer and highlighter is far outside the time I can devote to this :(, I'll have to stick with working with 2 editors.

Comment: @David, yeah, I had guessed it'd be quite a bit of work since I couldn't find anyone who already did this...

Comment: If I ever get to do it, I'll try to post the result here but do not hold you breath :P

Answer (score 2):

You could try the Tunnel Vision Labs extension. This can be found in [Microsoft Gallery](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/25b991db-befd-441b-b23b-bb5f8d07ee9f)

Comment: Thanks  :) I'll definitely have a look on that one :D